# Slide one div over two div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `div` . `div-1 and div-2` .it  need to stay all the time but i want some menu items using another `div` name `div-3`  which is visible when button clicks. i want div-3 over div-1 and div-2 at the same time .how can i do that ?
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe you can use position and display property with javascript to do the same.

Comment: Please add some code. You probably look for `position:absolute`

Comment: CSS is the proper tool for this task, namely, the `display` property. See the new CSS Grid which allows for overlapping. You would use CSS `transition` to move the `div`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JavaScript Notes

An [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is a very common design pattern in `JavaScript` commonly used to hide your code so that it doesn't get changed by other scripts.

You can add event listeners to elements using the [addEventListner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function.

You can get an HTMLElement using the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function which accepts a selector. So to get the first div you could use `document.querySelector("div")`. To get the element with id "item" you can use `document.querySelector("#item")`. To get the first element element with class "active" you can use `document.querySelector(".active")`. You can also use `document.querySelector("div#item.active")` to get the item the fills all the previous requirements or `document.querySelector("div, #item, .active")` to get the item that fills any of the requirements. As you can see this works the same as CSS selectors.

To check if a variable is an instance of a Class you can use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

There are several ways to change how an Element looks using JavaScript.
One is to change the class name `element.className = "active"`, another is to directly change the styling `element.style = "opacity: 1;"`.

### Styling Notes

To [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) an element on top of other elements you need to set its `position` to `absolute` and the container's element to `relative`. When you absolutely position an element then its positioned relatively to the last container that is positioned `relatively` (default is `<html>` element).

There are 2 main ways to position elements next to each other: `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;`. This works like writing on a notepad, it fits as many elements on next to each other and the repeats the same process below them.

There are 3 common ways to hide an element. **1:** `opacity: 0;` which just makes the item invisible but it it's still there so you should probably also use `pointer-events: none;` so that it doesn't stop you from clicking what's behind it. **2:** `height: 0;` This just shrinks the element so that it has no height which essentially makes it invisible. **3:** `display: block;` this essentially completely removes the element.

### Example

```js
// IIFE Design Pattern
(function() {
  // Run onLoad function if page is fully loaded
  if (document.readystate === "complete") onLoad();
  // Else add an event listener to call onLoad function when page gets fully loaded
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);

  var divIsActive = false;

  /**
   * Function to be called when page is fully rendered
   * @returns {void}
   */
  function onLoad() {
    // Find button
    var button = document.querySelector("#toggle");
    // Check if the button was found
    if (button instanceof HTMLElement) {
      // Add an click event listener
      button.addEventListener("click", toggle);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Toggles the div to open/close
   * @returns {void}
   */
  function toggle() {
    // Find Div
    var div = document.querySelector("#div-3");
    // Check if the div was found
    if (div instanceof HTMLElement) {
      // swap the boolean value
      divIsActive = !divIsActive;
      // change the classname based on the boolean value
      div.className = divIsActive ? "active" : "";
    }
  }

})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#div-1, #div-2 {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#div-1 {
  background-color: brown;
}

#div-2 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#div-3 {
  background-color: green;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#div-3.active {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}

#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
  <div id="div-1"></div>
  <div id="div-2"></div>
  <div id="div-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need js functionality . when button clicks then div 3 will visible over 2 divs.

Comment: @jobairahmed I am still editing the answer, it takes a while to write

Comment: @jobairahmed I added a basic snippet that should do what you asked for. I'm still editing my answer (adding comments and optimizing)

Comment: @jobairahmed I added some comments and notes, to help you understand how the code works. (If you like my answer you can upvote it)

Comment: I have already voted up.